# Real life math to explore/solve

Tags: integration, statistics, trigonometry

What are some examples of mathematics application in the real life that is interesting to explore about? And not too complicated but not too easy, something that exist around us. I'm interested in doing something related to integration, trigonometry and statistics. I currently taking an IB diploma (Maths HL course) so my knowledge on those topics is not really wide. Thus, I'm searching for real - life problem that up to my level to explore/solve? Thanks in advance

Comment: High 5 I am doing IB too. Doing my EE in maths. http://ibmathsresources.com/2013/09/03/maths-ia-exploration-topics/

Comment: Thanks for the link.Great for you to be able to do EE in maths. I'm doing my EE in ITGS. One more question, does my EE has to be something that out of the syllabus or something as simple as finding the volume of cupcake for example?

Comment: It may be worth (if still useful) to take a look at [this book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/free_download/9780262514293_Street_Fighting_Mathematics.pdf), for example chapter 3.

Comment: When you fill a glass to half height, how much of the total volume did you fill ? Glasses can be cylindrical, half-spherical, conic or parabolic.

Comment: You can always solve my homework that is definitely a real life problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Sports is always a great place to find "everyday" math challenges. Not sure how to work integration or trig into this, but exploring the relationship between the various statistics in, say, soccer or cricket would be very interesting. E.g., Does goals for and against a team have any predictive value about the number of games won?

For something more "scientific" you could look at the accuracy of your local weather forecaster as a function of forecast distance (e.g., 1 day ahead, 2 day ahead, etc).